# Save Export CSV to desired location - PHP

Tags: php

I have a code like this.

```
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0,pre-check=0");
header("Pragma: public");
```

Now, this gets saved in my desktop. If i wish to save the xls file in D:/xls/
then how to add the code.
Please help me.

Thanks -
Haan

Answer (score 3):

> If i wish to save the xls file in D:/xls/ then how to add the code.

The server **can not** dictate to the client where to save a file.

That is a decision *only* the client can make.

Imagine if the server could tell the client where to save a file.  You could overwrite any file on the user's system.  That'd be the biggest security breach in the history of poorly designed internet security breaches.